# PHP wildcards in code displays wildcard character

Tags: php, apache, wildcard

I have a problem when running a php code with wildcards. I noticed it when usin glob function

```
x = glob($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/images/SCHEMAS/EL/PNG/". "AW" . "???" . ".png", GLOB_NOCHECK);
print_r ($x);
```

will display

Array ( [0] => /var/www/html/images/SCHEMAS/EL/PNG/AW???.png )

instead of an array of all files starting with AW like PATH/AW-01.png

I dont think that there is a problem in the code but more in setting of our intranet web server with brand new installation of Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.

Code works on my XAMPP environment as well as on web hosting but not on intranet web server. 
I tried to change PHP.ini and played with httpd.conf but no success. This might be really easy but searching the internet for couple of days didnt help.

This is my first post to s-overflow so sorry if style not inline with post recommendation.

Comment: thanks for quick reply corrupt. Did that, that was actually how I started but result is the same. "AW*.PNG" displayed in browser

Answer (score 0):

[GLOB_NOCHECK](https://www.php.net/glob) means "return the search pattern if no matches are found."  It's possible your Web server process doesn't have access to the files in question.

Comment: thanks Steve, I can display the files individually. code is part of creating tab for variable number of images. When I target the files directly the images are displayed fine so I think access to files should be OK

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will help someone. The problem was in the path declaration with $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
avoiding this and giving a relative path was working on all servers ( XAMMP, ISP, INTRANET )

Previously only XAMMP accepted that statement.

Thanks.